# Gradle sync failed: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins. (8 s 991 ms)

Tags: java, android

When I update Android Studio new version I mean 5.1.1 gredle give some error that Gradle sync failed: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins. (8 s 991 ms). Please help me.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.beyza.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/raw'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'announce'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

I dont know how can I fix this.

````
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {


    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}```
````

Comment: post your app level gradle also

Answer (score 0):

Remove "apply plugin" from your dependency and set it at top of gradle like below:

Also if you have "apply plugin: 'java'" then remove it.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'announce'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.beyza.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/raw'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```